# ЧПУ на js с корректной обработкой перезагрузок

Tags: javascript, ajax, чпу

Стоит задача реализовать ЧПУ с корректной перезагрузкой страницы.

Конкретнее:

Я меняю адрес при клике по ссылкам при помощи history.pushState
У меня есть всего одна существующая страничка index.php
При клике по ссылкам подставляются адреса на подобии /about и т.п. но по получившемуся адресу страницы не существует.
При перезагрузке браузер пытается загрузить страницу по адресу в поисковике и выдает 404
Вот и вопрос, как это поправить.

Меня адрес при помощи обработки события beforeunload пробовал, адрес меняется но при перезагрузке используется некорректный адрес.
Использовать .htaccess не хочется. Хотелось бы сделать это без вмешательства сервера.
Использую нативный js, но библиотека тоже сойдет.

Comment: Использовать .htaccess или конфиг Nginx придётся, как минимум потому что любой адрес должен ссылаться у Вас в один файл, чтобы на JS можно было обработать URL и вывести какой-то результат.

Comment: А в react router реализации маршрутизации тоже основана на .htaccess или конфиге сервера? 
Может, кто-то знает, почему браузер при перезагрузке не использует адрес, измененный в beforeunload?

Comment: Основана внутри js, но изначально все адреса должны быть направлены на входящий файл. Иначе сам веб-сервер будет ссылаться на несуществующую страницу без скрипта с Вашим роутингом.

Comment: Есть одна идея. Возможно сделать запрос на сервер на создание фейковой страницы по тому адресу, что указан. В том файле будет скрипт, который восстановит состояние, как до перезагрузки...
Хотя вот пишу и думаю, что это костыль с участием сервера и лучше тогда сделать по нормальному.
Надо еще подумать.

Answer (score 0):

Короче, решение я нашел.
До безобразия тупое, криво, костыльное и прочие негативные прилагательные, но тем не менее оно работает.
А выглядит оно так:

```
window.onbeforeunload = () => {
            setInterval(() => {
                window.location.href = "/";
            }, 1)
        };
```

Да, я просто заспамил изменением location.href и это сработало :D
Я попробую довести до ума этот вариант и дополню ответ, если выйдет что-то годное, а пока так.

Comment: На самом деле мне очень стыдно за такое решение. Пока нет идей, как сделать нормально. Видимо, и правда нет способа обойтись без сервера.